# Display webpages in dynamic tabs

Tags: library, javascript, web-development

The website I'm working with involves a lot of report viewing. The design requirement is such that whenever the user chooses to open another page[from the navigation pane]; instead of replacing the existing page it needs to add another dynamic tab and display the same in the new tab. This is so that the user can go back and forth the tabs and view the necessary reports.

Now I'm not talking about opening the links on a new browser tab, but on the same page with a dynamic tab where the user can simply move back and forth the open dynamic tabs[webpages] quickly.

This was previously implemented using Smart GWT Tabs, but now we want to do away with Smart GWT hence looking for a better alternative to implement the same. Here's a quick image that I've edited to put across my thoughts. It starts off at first with a single tab[home page], adds on tabs which can be switched to later on as and when links are clicked on.The content of webpages that need to be opened in tabs would be mostly in a lot of nested tables, and have quite a bit of javascript to perform various other functions on the information displayed.

[image: Dynamic Tabs]

What are my best option(s) to achieve this other than SmartGWT or should I be sticking to it? Kindly do point me to where I could learn about the same as well if possible?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! What language are you using for your programming? Or would you be willing to change that for your project? Do you need Open Source software? Are you willing to pay for the software (if so, about how much?)

Comment: Another question is why do you want to "do away with SmartGWT"? I don't know this java package, but describing why it fails could help someone to better provide an alternative for you.

Answer (score 0):

[ejTab](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/azure/tab/defaultfunctionalities) which is a part of [Essential Studio for JavaScript](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript) can do dynamic tabs. Simple sample showing this:[link](http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/rjr3txtu)

The whole suite of controls is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify. Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something like this a few years ago for personal use.

My  [Recipes](https://rbutterworth.nfshost.com/Recipes/) page looks like:

[image: Multiple tabs, one for each category of food.]

which toggles back to the standard HTML list:

[image: Long list with separate headings for each category.]

And another, [Quora Answers by Ray Butterworth](https://rbutterworth.nfshost.com/Me/quora/) goes 4 levels deep:
`Top -> Religion → Bible → Holy Days -> answers`

[image: Multiple tabs, with more tabs in expanded section.]

You're welcome to steal a copy of it.
(If this is for commercial use and it proves useful to the company, you're also welcome to send me a suitable consulting fee. :-)